# Angular 11: Radio button is not set its default value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

We have the radio button(s) and it can't get set its default value during component rendering.

```
<ng-template #taxPaidTemplate>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label class="ari-label" for="isTaxPaid">Is Tax Paid</label>
        </div>
        <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
          <input formControlName="isTaxPaid" type="radio" [value]="true" /> Yes
          <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="ari-control ari-control-radio ari-control-inline">
          <input formControlName="isTaxPaid" type="radio" [value]="false" /> No
          <div class="ari-control-indicator"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

I am also setting up the default value of the isTaxPaid property at the typescript side:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      isTaxPaid: false,
      });
```

isTaxPaid is a boolean property.

Any thoughts on *No* radio button to be set by default?

Comment: `isTaxPaid: false` ?

Comment: yes it is set as false at the time of declaration... @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: I meant, without the square brackets, otherwise it's an array

Comment: yes, it is declared without square brackets.

Comment: Your question states `isTaxPaid: [false]` ...

Comment: I have just updated this.. please check now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a duplicate to [follwoing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643472/is-it-possible-to-have-html-normal-text-in-a-typescript-variable-in-angular)!

Anyhow, use the input property 'checked', this should do the trick

```
<input type="radio" [value]="true" [checked]="isTaxPaid" (click)="isTaxPaid = true"/>
```