# Is it possible to have html + normal text in a typescript variable in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my website, I am showing all of the contents from a Model file. Now, what I need to achieve is that having a ts variable which is String of content related to website as well an URL in  html tag. Of course, when the variable is executed in view, it simply shows everything as text. Could not find any resource in google regarding this.
Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have HTML stored in a string in the first place? That's the real problem. You can solve your problem here by using `innerHTML`, but that's dangerous and rarely necessary. The better solution would be to just not store HTML in a string and instead use the template to generate HTML.

Comment: The component followed "a heading, few image urls, List of String contents" format. Now, in the content part, the requirement is that I am having a URL for users to navigate to. I can break the previous structure which has been convenient so far, because I am having this "heading + image urls + content" part for good number of times and in future this will keep on adding. So that's why trying to look for something where in the content part itself, I can have <href> tag which will behave as html.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, all you need to do is to use the combine the regular text with the html content (preferably by using the backticks syntax, and of course sanitize it before binding it in the html template. Check the code snippet below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div [innerHtml]="htmlSanitizedContent"></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  regularTextAndHtmlStr = `This is the regular text part. And below it's the html part:
  <img src="https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/angular.svg" alt="something" />`;

  // This step is important for keeping your code secured!!
  // Binding html content that is not sanitized first is
  // extremely dangerous for you project.
  htmlSanitizedContent = this.sanitizer.sanitize(
    SecurityContext.HTML,
    this.regularTextAndHtmlStr
  );

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

Working StackBlitz sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsjdsp?file=src%2Fmain.ts

---

**Warning!** As written in the comment inside of the snippet, when binding html content in the template using `[innerHtml]` (or other similar constructs), it's mandatory to first sanitize that html code! Especially when working with URLs.

You might want to check the Angular's documentation on the matter for more security related details:

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer